# GWT and WeakHashMap

Tags: java, gwt

What would be my best bet for the implementation of an alternative to Java's `WeakHashMap`in GWT?

I understand there is no concept of `finalizer` in Javascript and thus the implementation of `weak references` is difficult but has somebody come up with a clever solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266704/is-it-possible-to-create-a-weak-reference-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible through [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) (supported in all major browsers)