# Javascript object with precise lifetime / run code at end of scope

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, object-lifetime

It is often helpful to have objects with a lifetime tightly related to scope. For example in C++, the destructor for auto objects. In C#, `Dispose` within a `using` block.

I want to know if there's a way to do this in Javascript.

The example that comes to mind is a logging object that can measure the time spent in a function. Something like this:

In C++:

```
void someFunction()
{
    LogScopeMessage lsm("in some function");
    ...
}
```

In C#:

```
private void someFunction()
{
    using(auto lsm = new LogScopeMessage("in some function"))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

.... and in Javascript what would be the best way to set up this kind of idiom?

Comment: Function scope variables, I'd say.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566307/javascripts-equivalent-of-destruct-in-object-model