# Can I monitor polymer elements detached() (disconnectedCallback() for 2.+) to make sure there is no memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

Am I correct in assuming that when an element is detached, i.e, its detached() method for Polymer 1.+ or disconnectedCallback() for Polymer 2.+ runs, all references to that element and its childs are removed and no memory leak can be associated with that element anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [`detached`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks)/[`disconnectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) are invoked when the element is removed from the document, but it does not indicate that there are no references to the element.

For example, a Polymer element could call `setInterval()` with a callback that holds a reference to one of its properties. Removing that element from the document (e.g., via [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)) does not automatically stop the timer, so it's possible for the element to remain in memory after no longer being in the document. `clearInterval()` should be called in order to avoid this.

- [demo (Polymer 1)](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yPydqN?editors=1010)
- [demo (Polymer 2)](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WXbqaV?editors=1010)

Also note JavaScript currently has no garbage collection semantics. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29333017/6277151)

Comment: Great explanation thanks. Any suggestion on how to approach finding memory leaks in Polymer elements or perhaps using Polymer doesn't change anything and I should still think pure JavaScript? just asking in case you have any input.

Comment: No problem :)   Regarding memory leaks in Polymer elements: That's such a broad topic, since practically any type of JS memory leak is possible in Polymer :) Here's a good reference on how to avoid and troubleshoot them: https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/